# how do I set this code so that each line has a different colour, dash and legend

Tags: matlab

I do not have good experience with graphics. I have written the matlab code below. I would like a beautiful graph with different color for each, different dashed lines and a legend.

```
 [y,b]=meshgrid(0.1:0.5:1.0,0.0:0.1:1.0);
  w=(y-y+1).*(b-b+1);
   nt=8.0.*w;
   nc=2.0.*w;
   a=5.0.*w;  
   b1= 10.0.*w;
   b2=10.0.*w;

 d1=-(b1.*b2)./(b2+(b1.*(1+b2)));
 d2=(-0.5.*(b2-(b1.*(1+b2))))./(b2+(b1.*(1+b2)));
 z0=d2+nt;
 z1=d1+d2+nt;
 z=(d1.*y)+d2+nt;
 e= (z0.^a).*(1+(2.*nc));
 d= (z1.^a).*((2.*nc)-1);
 p=(z1.^(a+1))-(z0.^(a+1));
 k1=(0.5.*d1.*(a+1).*(e-d))./p; 
 k2=((nt-nc).*(z0.^a).*(z1.^a))./p;
 e1=1+((k1.*b)./(d1.*(a+1)));
 e2= nt+(b.*nc);
 e3=(k2.*b)./((1-a).*(2-a));
 so= e1.*((z1.^3)-(z0.^3)); 
 s1= e2.*((z0.^2)-(z1.^2));
 s2= e3.*((z1.^(2-a))-(z0.^(2-a)));
 soo= e1.*(((z1.^3).*z0)-((z0.^3).*z1)); 
 s11= e2.*(((z0.^2).*z1)-((z1.^2).*z0));
 s22= e3.*(((z1.^(2-a)).*z0)-((z0.^(2-a)).*z1));
 k3=((so./6)+(s1./2)+s2)./d1;
 k4=-((soo./6)+(s11./2)+s22)./d1;
 u=(((-e1.*(z.^3))./6)+((e2.*(z.^2))./2)-(e3.*(z.^(2-a)))+(k3.*z)+k4).  /(d1.^2);
 w1=u
 [C,h]=contour(y,w1,b);
 set(h,'showText','on','textStep',get(h,'levelStep'))
```

Comment: A beautiful graph of *what*?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for plotting? All of those things are well defined in there. [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Comment: I guess you want to choose the colors for the different contours of the contour plot. To do so, obtain the contour line information using `contourc` instead of `contour`, and then plot the lines separately using `plot` or `line`.

Comment: Otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't even see an attempt to plot. Stack Overflow is a help forum, not one to do your work for you - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you A. Donda. Thats what I wanted.

Comment: @sani, since I seem to have guessed the right answer, I posted it as an answer. Feel free to upvote and/or accept it. ;-) You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to choose the colors for the different contours of the contour plot. To do so, obtain the contour line information using `contourc` instead of `contour`, and then plot the lines separately using `plot` or `line`.